# Note inside \cite brackets, at beginning instead of end

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I'd like to put a note inside `\cite` brackets, at the beginning, like this:

```
[e.g. 19,20]
```

with the space being non-breaking.

The optional argument makes puts *something* at the end:

```
\cite[e.g.]{refA,refB}
```

gives

```
[19;, 20, e.g.]
```

(though there are more commas and semicolons than I would like).

Is there a package or some other magic that will achieve this?

Comment: You should be able to write `\cite[e.g.][]{cite}`

Comment: @Seamus, that doesn't work for me unfortunately. :/

Answer (score 3):

The citing commands of [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) feature a second optional argument that does what you want. Note that if you only want to add a citation prenote, you have to use both optional arguments (with the postnote argument empty).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

See \autocite[99]{A01}.

See \autocite[e.\,g.][99]{A01}.

See \autocite[e\,.g.][]{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, OK. I think for the current project it may be too late in the game to introduce fundamental new stuff like biblatex, but I will definitely keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: @Reid: What bibliography packages, if any, do you use? IIRC, the second optional argument isn't a `biblatex`-exclusive trick.